# Compile-time assert using templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading code from the cpp-btree library of google (https://code.google.com/p/cpp-btree/) and I came accross that compile-time assert mechanism.

```
// A compile-time assertion.
template <bool>
  struct CompileAssert {
};

#define COMPILE_ASSERT(expr, msg) \
  typedef CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
```

So I understand more or less what it does, if expr is evaluated to false by the compiler it will declare a new type msg that will be a CompileAssert < false > array of size -1 which will trigger a compilation error.

What I don't get is the bool(expr) part, what is this exactly? Some kind of call to the copy constructor of the class bool? (but it's a builtin type so I'm confused)
I though this would be a mechanism to raise a compilation error when expr is not a boolean but actually I managed to compile a short program whit that line

```
COMPILE_ASSERT("trash",error_compilation_assert);
```

It compiles just fine with gcc 3.4

So can anyone explain the bool(expr) part of the mechanism?

Comment: It *forces* a conversion to `bool` for `expr`. `expr` might be something that is *convertible* to bool, but not actually a bool and as such would pose a problem for the template (since implicit conversions are not allowed there).

Comment: @Xeo Why would implicit conversions not be allowed?

Comment: @Angew How would the template know you are not creating a new specialization of it?

Comment: @NeilKirk Because there's no `template` keyword in the declaration? Note that class templates can't be "overloaded." [See live example](http://ideone.com/5iB34D).

Comment: Note: in C++ this is `static_assert(t + t * 4 == 0, "You should choose a better value of t");` which is able to provide better error messages :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a type conversion. There are 3 main types of type conversions in C++:

- Cast notation (C-style cast): `(bool) expr`
- Functional notation (constructor-style cast): `bool(expr)`
- Cast operators (C++-style cast); `static_cast<bool>(expr)`

Cast notation and functional notation are semantically equivalent (i.e. they both perform the strongest possible conversion, the C-cast), but the scope & precedence of the functional notation is clearer.

It is generally advised not to use them in C++ code and use the specific cast operators (`const_cast`, `static_cast` etc.) instead.

So in your code, it's just a way of forcing the value to type `bool` and enclosing it in parentheses at the same time, so that no operator priority issues arise.

Answer (score 3):

`bool(expr)` casts `expr` into a `bool`.

Comment: `(bool)expr` would be a cast. `bool(expr)` isn't a cast. It creates a temporary `bool`, initialized from `expr`.

Comment: @NikosC. It's a function-style cast. For basic data types, there is no practical difference between the two cases (as a cast results in a temporary).

Comment: @NeilKirk *Very* strictly speaking, it's not a cast, it's a type conversion. But I fully agree with you that outside of the standard, these two are used interchangeably, with no harm.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter should be some kind of expression, such as `a == b`. Using a string literal here is useless.

`bool(expr)` is a function-style cast which converts the expression to a bool. Lots of things convert implicitly to bool, but I guess they wanted an explicit cast to make sure the result is a bool.

If you convert a pointer to a bool, it evaluates to false if it is a NULL pointer, or true otherwise. Your string literal "Trash" decays into a `const char *` to the first character. As this is not a null pointer, the expression evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

bool(expr) tries to convert expr to bool either implicitly or using any user defined conversion operator.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can instantiate built-in types with ctor syntax:

```
bool b1 = bool(true);
bool b2 = bool(b1);
```

The difference to:

```
bool b2 = b1;
```

is that the latter does an implicit conversion to bool. When such an implicit conversion isn't allowed (as in the template typedef), then `bool(b1)` makes it explicit by creating a temporary `bool` from `b1` and the temporary doesn't have to be converted anymore; it's an actual `bool` type.